# Kettle to pot, Hello? Come in, pot

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

In the tv series *Mentalist* S03E1: the character Rigsby uses the phrase

> Kettle to pot. “Hello. Come in, pot.”

I wonder what it means. You can see the timestamp at the [Quodb website](http://www.quodb.com/search/kettle%20to%20pot%20hello%20come%20in%20pot).

Comment: Related: [The meaning of the English idiom “pot calling the kettle black”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127144/the-meaning-of-the-english-idiom-pot-calling-the-kettle-black) and [Is there a word for using half an idiom or saying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340622/370839#370839)

Comment: I've usually heard this as "Pot to Kettle, come in Kettle"

Comment: Most commonly I've heard this as "Pot - meet kettle". This is equivalent to introducing two people, e.g. "Jack- meet Diane" or "Jack, this is Diane" or "Jack- Diane".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's a reference to the proverbial idiom ["The pot calling the kettle black"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pot_calling_the_kettle_black). This has more recently been reworked into the simpler "pot, kettle" reference to invoke the idiom.

As others have noted, the "X to Y. Hello. Come in, Y." format is used to mimic the start of a radio conversation. It's used to get the listener's attention and is essentially saying "hey, are you listening?".

So, combined, "Kettle to pot. Hello. Come in, pot." is simply drawing attention to the fact that the person being spoken to is guilty of the same thing that they are accusing the speaker of.

Comment: Noteworthy is that when this proverb first came about, pots and kettles were almost always made from cast iron, and thus were, in fact, black in color.  It makes less sense these days when such dishes come in all sorts of colors, and black is far less common than it used to be.  (Most common now seems to be either shiny metallic, or ceramic white.)

Comment: I see there are answers addressing both aspects of this, but I think it would be helpful for this (the top-voted and accepted answer) to also include a brief explanation of "X to Y. Hello. Come in, Y." which is a mock radio transmission.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: New cast iron pots & kettles aren't black, they're a sort of silvery-grey.  The black comes from being used over open flames, since soot condenses on the colder metal of the pot.  Most of the black soot rubs off on any available surface after you take it off the fire, but a little stays in the pores of the metal.  Of course cooking over open fires was standard practice in the days before electric & gas stoves, and still happens when camping.

Comment: More focused: "X to Y. Hello. Come in, Y." => X is _calling_ Y.

Comment: @jamesqf I have several cast iron pots and pans myself, none of which have ever come near open flames (I've always had electric burners).  They are all black, inside and out, have always been black, and it does not rub or scrape off (which rules out some sort of coating or soot).  I think you're thinking of polished iron, which these are not.  Might have to do with the level of purity of the iron or something.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: Or you may have purchased pre-seasoned cast iron cookware.  You also get the same coloring just from use (though it takes longer) as cooking oil works into the pores and is partly burned.  But the color that comes from seasoning doesn't rub off, unlike the soot from open fires.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman James is correct.  Cast iron is actually grayish in its natural state, but cast iron cookware usually comes with a pre-applied seasoning that is dark black.  The original idiom refers more to the fact that both were commonly used over smoky wood or coal fires, which left soot all over them.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Okay, but point is that for the vast majority of their use, i.e. except when they are absolutely brand new, they are going to be black.  The soot might wipe off, but not the seasoning, so the point still stands.  Black is still the most common and expected color for iron cookware.  Arguing over the exact reason for it is just splitting hairs.

Comment: It's worth noting in this day and age that calling someone or something "black" was historically derogatory in context. So the person being spoken to is guilty of the same thing that they are accusing the speaker of.  There's nothing inherently "wrong" with being "black", never has been.  One could just as easily say, "the pot calling the kettle cookware" without losing any meaning and without perpetuating "legacy" word choices.

Comment: @jamesqf Actually, when camping you very often cook over gas.  If you're in an area that is at all popular that permits open fires you won't find suitable firewood within a reasonable distance, usually you will have to buy it locally at high prices.  (Bringing it in is usually prohibited.)  In **many** places open fires simply aren't allowed anyway and sometimes certain fuels are even restricted.  (For example, rules saying fire must have an off switch.)

Comment: @Loren Pechtel: You obviously live or go camping in different places than I do.  But remember that the state of things today, whether it's camping stoves or pre-seasoned cast iron cookware - are not what they were when this saying originated.

Answer (score 20):

By the way . . .

The first translation of Don Quixote brought to England a proverb about a pot calling a kettle ‘black-eyes’. In less than twenty years it had been thoroughly Englished to become

> The pot calls the pan burnt-arse.

It was then included in John Clarke’s 1639 collection of proverbs, *Parœmiologia Anglo-Latina.*

In conversation with his fellow prisoners, Cervantes himself probably said black-arse (*culinegra* in Spanish) rather than black-eyes (*ojinegra*). After all, whether it’s a pan or a kettle, black or burnt, it has no eyes, and what happens happens to its arse!

Changing social mores (probably Victorian ones) did for *burnt-arse*. Just as they did for *white-arse*, the apt name given to the upland bird now known as the wheatear, whose ears are nothing to write home about but whose white rump is conspicuous in flight. It is known in France as *cul-blanc*. No ‘épis de blé’ for *them*!

Comment: My dad's a birder so I've picked up quite a lot, but I'd never heard that about the origins of the wheatear.  Thank you!

Comment: By the way, those coy Victorian lexicographers derived 'wheatear' from 'white-arse' by splitting the words wrongly to make **whit-earse**, which they decided must be the plural of **whit-ear**. And **Whit**, they said, was a dialect form of **whete**, meaning **wheat**. I daresay ordinary folk carried on calling it by its real name for years.

Comment: Those two Spanish adjective-headed compounds, *culinegra* and *ojinegra*, remind of a rather interesting paper I just read concerning [“The syntactic structure of *pelirrojo* compounds”](https://www.glossa-journal.org/articles/10.5334/gjgl.746/print/) and the notion of inalienable possession relationships.

Comment: @Graham Sorry. I wrote a reply but must have failed to post it. I picked up a fair bit from *my* dad too. He was a real countryman: spoke *mannerly* to magpies and called an elder a bottery. It was him wondering why on earth they were called wheatears that got me looking into it. Not many white-arses in Brixton(!) but blackcaps and a great spotted woodpecker arrived this year, along with nesting house sparrows, which are a rarity here these days.

Answer (score 8):

"Come in, pot" is a play on words.  You don't hear it much anymore, but in old TV shows (and probably radio before that), you would hear people (usually military or cops) on a two-way radio say something like:

> "Car 17 to headquarters.  Come in, headquarters."

when establishing a radio conversation.

And, of course, each side would say "Over" when they were finished speaking and ready for the other side to speak; "Over and out" when the conversation was done.

Comment: > "Over and out" when the conversation was done.

[Common misconception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_word#OVER)

Comment: @scubbo - What??  You think they lied in "Highway Patrol", "Sky King", and half a dozen other TV shows???